# How to grep to include an optional word?

Tags: grep

I use the following grep query to find the occurrences of functions in a VB source file.

```bash
    grep -nri "^\s*\(public\|private\|protected\)\s*\(sub\|function\)" formName.frm
```

This matches -

```vb
    Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    Private Sub lbSelect_Click()
    ...
```

However, it misses out on functions like -

```vb
   Private Static Sub SaveCustomer()
```

because of the additional word "Static" in there. How to account for this "optional" word in the grep query?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use a `\?` to make something optional:

```bash
grep -nri "^\s*\(public\|private\|protected\)\s*\(static\)\?\s*\(sub\|function\)" formName.frm
```

In this case, the preceding group, which contains the string "static", is optional (i.e. may occur 0 or 1 times).

Comment: @CodeBlue a literal ?. When you invoke `grep` this way, it uses BRE (basic regular expressions). In BRE, you need to escape many of the metacharacters for "more advanced" expressions. As noted in another answer, if you had passed -E then you would have not had to escape it (in fact, escaping it would cause it to match a literal ? mark!).

Answer (score 12):

When using grep, cardinality wise:

```
* : 0 or many
+ : 1 or many
? : 0 or 1 <--- this is what you need.
```

Given the following example (where the **very** word stands for your **static**):

```
I am well
I was well
You are well
You were well
I am very well
He is well
He was well
She is well
She was well
She was very well
```

If we only want

```
I am well
I was well
You are well
You were well
I am very well
```

we'll use the '?' (also notice the careful placement of the space after 'very ' to mention that we'll want the 'very' word zero or one time:

```bash
egrep "(I|You) (am|was|are|were) (very )?well" file.txt
```

As you guessed it, I am inviting you to use **egrep** instead of **grep** (you can try **grep -E**, for Extended Regular Expressions).

Comment: what does egrep do that grep doesn't?

Comment: I think you meant grep -E with the uppercase E.

Comment: As you probably noticed, egrep recognizes extended regular expressions. And I fixed my answer. It is uppercase E indeed, thanks.

Comment: Do you have a solution for MacOS as well?